# AngularJs Syntax Error Token on ng-repeat tab for navigation

Tags: angularjs, navigation, syntax-error, angularjs-ng-repeat

repeat to iterate through convo object on the left column to create tabs, and want to render appropriate convo/:id on the right side as I click on the tab.

however I'm getting this error in browser console

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'f6e0ce4010000' is unexpected, expecting [}] at column 17 of the expression [{id: 5595e855646f6e0ce4010000}] starting at [f6e0ce4010000}].
```

and in browser inspection elements seem to render okay

```
<a ng-repeat="convo in convos" ui-sref="conversation.show({id: 5595e855646f6e0ce4010000})" class="ng-scope">
convo.title
```

### Here are my code

my view

```
%div.collection.convo-tab-container
  %a{'ui-sref'=>'conversation.show({id: {{convo._id.$oid}}})','ng-repeat'=>'convo in convos'}
    convo.title  
%div{class: 'col s8'}
  %div{'ui-view' => true}
```

angularJs

```
var convoWidget = angular.module('convoWidget',['ngResource','templates','msgPopup','ngRoute','ui.router']);

convoWidget.config(function($stateProvider){
  $stateProvider
    .state('conversation.show',{
      url: '/conversation/:id',
      templateUrl: 'conversation-show.html',
      controller: 'convoCtrl'
    })

});

convoWidget.controller('convoCtrl',['$scope','$http','Conversation',function($scope,$http,Conversation){

  $scope.currentUserId
  $scope.convos = [] ;
  $scope.defaultPicUrl = 'http://i.imgur.com/P25qqYM.png'

  $scope.otherUserName = function(convo){
    var other, fullName ;
    if(convo.author_id.$oid === $scope.currentUserId){
      other = convo.recipient
    }else if(convo.recipient_id.$oid === $scope.currentUserId){
      other = convo.author
    }
    fullName =  other.firstname + ' ' + other.lastname ;
    if(fullName.trim().length == 0){
      return 'Anonymous User'
    }
    return fullName ;
  }

  $scope.otherUserPic = function(convo){
    var picUrl ;
    if(convo.author_id.$oid === $scope.currentUserId){
      if(picUrl = convo.recipient.profile.avatar.small.url){
        return picUrl
      }else{
        return $scope.defaultPicUrl
      }
    }else if(convo.recipient_id.$oid === $scope.currentUserId){
      if(picUrl = convo.author.profile.avatar.small.url){
        return picUrl
      }else{
        return $scope.defaultPicUrl
      }
    }
  }

  $scope.lastMsgPreview = function(convo){
    var content, limit = 30 ;
    content = convo.messages[convo.messages.length - 1].body
    if(content.length > limit){
      return content.slice(0,limit-1) + ' ' + '...' ;
    }
    return content ;
  }

  $scope.lastMsgCreatedDate = function(scope){
    var msg = scope.messages[scope.messages.length - 1]
    return new Date(Date.parse(msg.created_at));
  }




  // functions for msg directive

  $scope.creatorPic = function(msg){
    var picUrl ;
    picUrl = msg.creator.profile.avatar.small.url;
    if(picUrl){
      return picUrl ;
    }else{
      return $scope.defaultPicUrl ;
    }
  }

  $scope.msgCreatedDate = function(msg){
    return new Date(Date.parse(msg.created_at));
  }

  $scope.creatorName = function(msg){
    var creator, creatorId, creatorFullName
    creator = msg.creator;
    creatorId = creator._id.$oid;
    creatorFullName = creator.firstname + ' ' + creator.lastname;

    if(creatorId === $scope.currentUserId){
      return 'Me' ;
    }else{
      var fullName = creatorFullName.trim.length == 0 ? 'Anonymous User' : creatorFullName ;
      return fullName ;
    }
  }

  $scope.msgContent = function(msg){
    return msg.body
  }

  $scope.refresh = function(){
    Conversation.getLatestConvos()
      .then(function(data){
        $scope.convos = data.conversations ;
        console.log($scope.convos[0])
        $scope.currentUserId = data.current_user ;
      })
  }
  $scope.refresh();
}])

convoWidget.directive('convoTab',function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'convo-tab.html',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      convoObj: '=',
      convoId: '=',
      otherUserName: '&',
      otherUserPic: "&",
      lastMsgPreview: '&',
      lastMsgCreatedDate: '&'
    }
  }
})

convoWidget.directive('msg',function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'msg.html',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      creatorPic: '&',
      msgObj: '=',
      msgCreatedDate: '&',
      dateFormat: '@',
      creatorName: '&',
      msgContent: '&'
    }
  }
})
```

Thank you so much for reading and any help would be appreciated :D
happy coding!

Comment: Think the value 5595e855646f6e0ce4010000 needs to be enclosed with inverted commas. So in your view try `'conversation.show({id: \'{{convo._id.$oid}}\'})'`

Comment: thank you so much! that got rid of the error